# Apache CXF LoggingFeature settings

Tags: java, logging, cxf

I added the Logging feature to my cxf service. It's great for debugging but I'd like to have the ability to stop the logging and start it again if necessary.

My solution: Changing the log level at `org.apache.cxf.services`. It works but I'm worried that it might suppress other messages. (I'm using several services, so `org.apache.cxf.services.servicename` not really an option).

Is there any other solution? Changing the `LoggingFeature`'s level to debug, or adding/removing feature at a running service for example.

I'm using CXF version 2.7.15.

Comment: which loggin framework you are using?

Comment: SLF4J 1.6.1 with Log4j 1.2.17 implementation